# What is this glitch/corruption?

Tags: digital-recording, avi

A while ago I was uploading some old videos on my computer, and I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rOhLfkCAVds&t=576s),and thought glitching on it looked really interesting, and I wanted more info on it. However, I couldn't find any info about this specific type of corruption, and I'm not sure if this has happened to someone else before or if it's a result of damage to my hard drive.
Thanks!

Comment: Hi, welcome to Video Production Stack Exchange.  Can you add some description of the glitch you are talking about.  As it currently stands, if anything happens to the video clip you have linked, the question will not have any meaning on its own.

Comment: @AJHenderson It seems to be quite a complicated glitch. It includes a strange high-pitched screeching/buzzing noise, and it seems to "merge" different frames together and move them randomly. A lot of the "activity" seems to be concentrated near the bottom. I also think I should mention that while I could play it on Youtube, the actual file would open up normally (I think).